# How to use a while loop to check if a variable is empty or not

Tags: bash, shell

I am using following code to check whether variable is empty or not.

I'm using a while loop because I need to continue the loop while the variable is empty. The moment the variable is set to a value the loop should exit.

```
MR=[]
while [ -z "$MR" ]
do 
    echo "in while loop"
    sleep 10s
    MR="hi"
done
```

For some reason, it is not at all executing. What is the reason?

Comment: `[]` is not an empty array. It's a literal string `[]`, which is not the empty string.

Comment: An empty array would be `MR=()` (ignoring the fact that `MR=()` doesn't actually define a variable; it only sets the array attribute on the name `MR`).

Comment: ok. got it. so can you suggest how to write while loop if any specific command is returning literal string or not . and continue the loop unless the variable is not empty literal string

Comment: @chepner What's the difference between defining a variable and setting the array attribute? I'm not familiar with the distinction.

Comment: `MR=()` is basically equivalent to `declare -a MR`. `MR` will still test as undefined with `[[ -v MR ]]`, for example, but `declare -p MR` will show it as `declare -a MR=()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the reason?

`MR` variable is not empty, it contains two characters `[` and `]`.

```
$ MR=[]
$ echo "$MR"
[]
```

Because it is not empty, `[ -z "$MR" ]` returns nonzero, so `while` is never executed.

Instead set the variable to en empty string.

```
MR=
# or, does the same, but for some is more readable:
MR=""
# or
MR=''
```